# IntelliJ IDEA's recognition of the tilde or "and" (FunctionalBuilder) in Play framework (Scala)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework

I have code like (copied from Play framework documentation):

```
implicit val locationReads: Reads[Location] = (
  (JsPath \ "lat").read[Double] ~
  (JsPath \ "long").read[Double]
)(Location.apply _)
```

which compiles and runs fine.  IntelliJ IDEA (version 14.1.2 as well as older versions back to 13) however doesn't recognise the functional builder (tilde or "and") and flags it up as error.

Does anyone know of a good workaround to get IDEA to be more intelligent about this?

Comment: IDEA 15, still the same issue